# ExpressJS creates a new session on each page change

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, node.js-connect

I'm trying to implement Express and Passport sessions like so:

```
  app.use(connect.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    cookie: {
      path: "/",
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: null
    },
    store: redisStoreConnect,
    secret: "something",
    key: 'pksy.sid'
  }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  passport.serializeUser (user, done) ->
    done null, user.email
    return

  passport.deserializeUser (email, done) ->
    User.findOne
        email: email
      , (err, user) ->
        done err, user
        return 
    return
```

If I navigate to a page in my site, a new session is created and stored in redis. If I refresh that page, the session appears to persist. If I navigate to a new page or even if I close the tab and reopen to the same page, a new session is created.

This is especially frustrating since Passport only authenticates the session that was generated for my login page. How do I get my sessions to persist across pages?

**Update:** Thanks @robertklep for reminding me to check what cookie the browser was actually sent back (which I should have done to start). It turns out the browser is sending back the right cookie, and the authentication is working. The sessions are in fact persisting, but for some reason a new session (unused by the browser) gets created with each page request. How can I stop this?

Comment: How do you configure passport? Also, does it help if you set `maxAge` to a timeout value (number of milliseconds the session can be valid)?

Comment: I set the maxAge to 604800000, and the error remains. Those are the only two passport lines I think would affect the session stuff. Other than them I'm just using a local strategy and an anonymous strategy.

Comment: Are you also using `passport.serializeUser()` and `passport.deserializeUser()`?

Comment: Oh yeah, those guys. I added them to the question.

Comment: While we're at it, could you post your call to `passport.authenticate` as well? I'm using a pretty similar setup (but using `express.cookieSession` instead of a Redis-backed store) and that works just fine.

Comment: I'm using the passport-anonymous library for everything right now. For each route, it's called something like `app.all '/', passport.authenticate('anonymous'), (req, res, next)->
    mvc('index', 'index', req, res, next)` Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: Tried removing the authenticate line to no effect.

Comment: I'm only using a local strategy myself. I think you're gonna need to debug the HTTP requests to see which cookies are send and received :(

Comment: Done! See edits above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Oh, you didn't know the browser doesn't send the session cookie with the request for the favicon?" says my roomate the hacker, whose ilk created the need for the following single line of code.

11 hours of debugging later here is what solved the problem:

```
app.use express.favicon()
```

Express was treating the favicon like any other resource, while the browser was making a specialized, apparently cookieless request for it. Express assumed this request must have come from a client without a session cookie, so it created a new session for them; a session never to be called upon again. `express.favicon()` saves the day!

Comment: Might have to do with the order in which you call middleware, but hey, when it works it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to use

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

before

```
app.use(app.router);
```

Hope this can help.